# this.props.navigation is undefined (createStackNavigator)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I would like to create a simple navigation example on ReactNative.

Here is a code below;

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home</Text>
        <Button
          title="To the detail Page"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('DetailScreen')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class Detail extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Detail Page</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default createStackNavigator({
  HomeScreen: { screen: Home },
  DetailScreen: { screen: Detail },
})
```

When I code like this, an error is occurred as Line12 `this.props.navigation` is undefined.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: can you specify how you call that component ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import {

      createAppContainer
    } from 'react-navigation';
    import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home</Text>
        <Button
          title="To the detail Page"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('DetailScreen')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class Detail extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Detail Page</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const APpStack =  createStackNavigator({
  HomeScreen: { screen: Home },
  DetailScreen: { screen: Detail },
})

const App = createAppContainer(APpStack);

export default App;
```

You can also check the working solution [link expo](https://snack.expo.io/r1R4Pcoar)

hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Answer (score 0):

You need a constructor to define properties that are used for storing navigation data (among others):

```
class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // ...
  }
```